# Rendering table with dynamically created tags in flask template

Tags: python, html, flask

I am dynamically creating html table tags from mongodb data with `json2html` in python flask application. If I copy the tags generated to html file it gives perfect output.

But I don't know how to pass those tags to the html template for rendering.

Table tag

```
<table border="1"><tr><th>Hemoglobin</th><td>10.4</td></tr><tr><th>WBC</th><td>35,450</td><tr><th>RBC</th><td>3.88</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Render call

```
return render_template('results.html',table=table)
```

Template

```
...
{{table}}
...
```

If I could simply substitute my table string into html template as a html code, I think my problem is solved. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe) filter. In this case html will not be escaped.
Like this:

```
{{table | safe}}
```

Comment: Seems like I was just 1 step close to answer. Worked like charm. Thanks